# Setting cookie in php

Tags: php, cookies

I'm trying to set the cookie, but it is not being set.

```
$hp = explode('=', $hp);
$shp = $hp[0];

echo $hp_id=$hp[1];

if(empty($_cookie['betahomepage1'])) {
    setcookie('betahomepage1',$hp_id,$expire,"/");
    echo "cookie not set";   
} else {
    echo "cookie is set";   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you run into a problem with a PHP function, double check all parameters and re-read the PHP manual about them.

The function in question is:

- [`setcookie`](http://de.php.net/setcookie)

You wrote:

```
setcookie('betahomepage1', $hp_id, $expire , "/"   , "https://www.mtsbeta.com");
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          $name          , $value, $expire , $path , $domain
```

The domain parameter *is not* a HTTP URI. It is just the Domain:

> **domain**
>   The domain that the cookie is available to. Setting the domain to `'www.example.com'` will make the cookie available in the www subdomain and higher subdomains. Cookies available to a lower domain, such as 'example.com' will be available to higher subdomains, such as `'www.example.com'`. Older browsers still implementing the deprecated [» RFC 2109](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2109) may require a leading . to match all subdomains.

Comment: i ahve removed the domain name. i have set the another cookie on the same page. both cookies have same code just variiables are different. second cookie is working but first one is not working.

Comment: Next step is to learn that `setcookie` has a return value. Check that value for errors. Also you might want to enable error reporting and such.

Answer (score 0):

The predefined variable in PHP that contains all cookies is called `$_COOKIE` (notice the uppercase), [see the page in the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php).

[As variables in PHP are case sensitive](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php), the `$_cookie` variable you are comparing against will be `NULL`, unless explicitly set somewhere else.

So, your cookie is being set, but you're not correctly retrieving it.

Also, a nice way to debug cookies is to use [FireBug](https://getfirebug.com/) (Or the Chrome developer tools); They can show you all active cookies in the browser.

If you want to make absolutely sure a cookie has been set in PHP during debug, you could just go for a `var_dump($_COOKIE)`, which will definitively tell you which cookies are set for the current request.